# slider loop and Pause on hover

Tags: jquery, loops, slider

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to create an infinite loop for the slider and temporarily stop on hover. I have to how to get this.

```js
function SlideLeft() {
  marginleft = $(".slideinner-style").css("left");
  marginleft = marginleft.replace("px");
  currentindex = $("#currentindex").val();

  if (currentindex == 1)
    return;

  $(".sliderightinner-style").show();

  if (parseInt(currentindex) - 1 == 1)
    $(".slideleftinner-style").hide();

  $("#currentindex").val(parseInt(currentindex) - 1);

  holderwidth = $(".slideinnerholder-style").css("width");
  holderwidth = holderwidth.replace("px");

  $(".slideinner-style").animate({
    "left": (parseInt(marginleft) + parseInt(holderwidth)) + "px"
  }, "slow");
}


function SlideRight() {
  marginleft = $(".slideinner-style").css("left");
  marginleft = marginleft.replace("px");
  holderwidth = $(".slideinnerholder-style").css("width");
  holderwidth = holderwidth.replace("px");
  currentindex = $("#currentindex").val();
  blockcount = $("#blockcount").val();

  if (currentindex == blockcount)
    return;

  $(".slideleftinner-style").show();

  if (parseInt(currentindex) + 1 == blockcount)
    $(".sliderightinner-style").hide();

  $("#currentindex").val(parseInt(currentindex) + 1);

  $(".slideinner-style").animate({
    "left": (parseInt(marginleft) - parseInt(holderwidth)) + "px"
  }, "slow");
}

function autoplay() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    SlideRight();
  }, 3000);
}
autoplay();
```

I use this code to loop the slider

```
$('.slideinner-style').delay(3500).fadeOut(500, SlideRight);
```

But it did not work as intended. Any suggestions?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/excdkfvL/

Comment: are you using bootstrap-slider or any other library for slider?

Comment: I use this library: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js

Comment: @user6250770 Can you help me loop the slider?

Comment: why to go with pure js.. use bootstrap carousel.. there you have multiple options.. if you want i can post that answer here

Comment: help me. I want to loop the slider and pause it when I hover over it. My knowledge of js cannot afford to do this. Thank you

Comment: i am using bootstrap frame work along with jquery library. Please check answer

Comment: Thanking you. Your answer will document me reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
       interval: 2000,
    cycle: true,
    pause: "null"
    });
    
});

$('#myCarousel').hover(function() {
    $(this).carousel('pause');
}, function() {
    $(this).carousel('cycle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

  <!-- Menu -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
    
  <!-- Items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
      
      <!-- Item 1 -->
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1500/600/?image=1"/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>
          <p>This is an example layout with carousel that uses the Bootstrap 3 styles.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>
        </p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
      <!-- Item 2 -->
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1500/600/?image=2"/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
          <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
      <!-- Item 3 -->
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1500/600/?image=3" />
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>
          <p>With "mobile-first" there is now only one percentage-based grid.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>  
 
</div>
```

Hope this may help you.